# Jquery if an ID is equal to "X" OR "Y" do not run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I would like to know if there's a way to bypass/turn off/not execute a function if the id is equal to "x" or "y".

I have installed this function that animates anchor links to their respective areas/anchors on the page. i.e. if I click on the button it animates down the page to the area that the button is referencing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

...which is working with any href that has a #.

I need to add a show more area using SCSS function on the same page.  I have added the example here: https://codepen.io/ojbravo/pen/YPJpXe

Which works on it's own, but uses the animation above since it has a # in the href area.  Therefore, the page does a shimmy up and down before it "Shows more".  I hate it and want it gone

What I would like to do is turn off the anchor animation above for these two links on the page with an ID of "show-rm" and "hide-rm" when the link is clicked.

This is the code on the page:

```
<div class="panel-wrapper-rm">
<a href="#show-rm" class="show-rm btn-rm" id="show-rm">Show Full Article</a> 
<a href="#hide-rm" class="hide-rm btn-rm" id="hide-rm">Hide Full Article</a> 
<div class="panel-rm">

<p>fkjadsljfal;s kadfjas jkdajfkl;das jfklajfkl;a jadkljfkadl jdjfl;da
   jk fl;kadjf kl;asdjfkl jdaklfj akl;jd flk;ajd l;kjflk;adj
   fkl;adjfkdj kl;adjfklda jlkajflka jlk;fj daklsjfkldj kaljfkl;adj
   kl;fjadl ;jfal;jd fklj fkasjf l;kajalk;j fkl;dj klajdfakls;d
   jfl;akdfj adkjfl ajfd
</p>



 </div><!-- end panel -->
 <div class="fade-rm"></div>
</div><!-- end panel-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to exclude some selection from your selector

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not(#show-rm,#hide-rm)')
```

Or the cleaner [.not](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not('#show-rm,#hide-rm')
```